# weird behavior in vs code on ubuntu vm

Tags: windows, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine

I was trying to open vs code on my Oracle VM Ubuntu 22.04 but it keeps glitching.
Any other app is working just fine, but here I have strange characters and bugging Open Folder window.
[what I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqetA.png)
My main system is Windows 10

I tried reinstall VS code but it didnt work.

Comment: read [this](https://betterprogramming.pub/5-tips-to-boost-the-performance-of-your-vs-code-editor-ff28dda68d9b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling 3D acceleration in VM setting helped[image: lped]